# Network connected device to manipulate HDMI-CEC?

Tags: hdmi, remote-control, television

I have a relatively new HDTV I'm working with, and I'd like a device to remotely control the TV through [HDMI-CEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#CEC). Ideally, I would be able to sit back and have a web console to control those things.

- I have WiFi, Ethernet would be a stretch to get to the TV
- My budget is ~$50-$100. Lower is better.
- Bonus points if it works over the open Internet, with proper authentication.

I have a DVD player and DIRECTV box attached, if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on a forum.

> i was using OpenELEC 5.0.5 for RPi1 on my old RPi1B+ and CEC was
>   working well on my TV. today, i just received my new RPi2 and i
>   installed OpenELEC 5.0.5 for RPi2. also here CEC is working well

Several people have report being able to do this with a raspberry pi 2.  The device is $35 and you will need a 5v power supply,SD card, usb wifi adapter.

The raspberry pi 3 has a built-in wifi adapter if you go with that model.

The rest you would have to research on the exact details of how.

Regarding the bonus points, Raspberry Pi, all versions, run linux and therefore support apache.  You can add a certificate from the **letsencrypt** project and setup a login screen.